# XPath selector for element which contains text in any decendent

Tags: xpath

How would I write a selector which searches for an element which contains specific text in any of its children.

This is what I have so far, but alas it doesn't work:

div.taskBlock[contains(., 'Open Activities')]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
.//div[contains(@class, 'taskBlock') and .//*[contains(., 'Open Activities')]]
```

It finds `div` that contains class name `taskBlock` **and** it has descendants that contain text "Open Activities".

Comment: Two issues with this: `contains(@class, 'taskBlock')` can result in false positives (it would also select `class="taskBlockItem"`, for example). And a separate `.//*[contains(., 'Open Activities')]` test is not necessary. To test *"contains the text `'Open Activities'` in any of the descendants"* using `contains(., 'Open Activities')` directly would be enough. The OP spoke of "children", though, not descendants.

Comment: This works. My problem was mostly using the .class syntax, which apparently xpath doesn't support for some reason.

Comment: @Joren Not for "some reason", but because your expectations don't match reality. XPath is way more powerful than (and completely different from) CSS selectors, of course `div.taskBlock` does not work.

Comment: All I meant was that since xpath is used by the same people that use css selectors, you might expect it to carry over syntax cues where possible. There's a reason lots of libs use css syntax for selectors.